# Importing json data using D3.json function returns null

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I've been trying to extract json data to build graphics with d3 but I can't seem to get the json loaded into a var properly.

The code is pretty simple:

test.js

```
d3.json("/js/data.json", function(error, graph) {
  alert(error)
})
```

This returns null in both chrome and firefox. data.length returns undefined.

index.html

```
<html>
<title>Streamgraph</title>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/test.js"></script>
</style>
</html>
```

I'm hosting the index.html on a barebone setup with Express on Node. According to Chrome, the data.json file is being fetched to completion. The console in Chrome doesn't report any errors. The data.json file has been validated with jsonlint.

I don't know where to go from here. I've read all the other stackoverflow posts on this issue, but all of them are related to CORS. I think my file is being loaded so I don't think its an access restriction issue.

While tracing d3 I see an error here:

```
function respond() {
      var status = request.status, result;
      if (!status && d3_xhrHasResponse(request) || status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304) {
        try {
          result = response.call(xhr, request);
        } catch (e) {
          dispatch.error.call(xhr, e);
          return;
        }
        dispatch.load.call(xhr, result);
      } else {
        dispatch.error.call(xhr, request);
      }
    }
```

In my execution, result is correctly populated with the JSON, but as soon as dispatch.load.call is reached, I get a popup with undefined, using

```
d3.json("/js/data.json", function(error, data) {
  alert(data.length)
})
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like the variable that holds the data is `graph` and not `data`.

Comment: data.length would be undefined, as your function parameter is graph. Have you tried graph.length?

Comment: Yeah, I mean this is undefined:

d3.json("/js/data.json", function(data) {
  alert(data.length)
});

Answer (score 0):

Basic mistake, data.length is undefined. data is correctly defined.